# android fragment replace to second fragment not working

Tags: android

My situation is I have a Activity(only FrameLayout),one fragment has a butoon that it's function is changing to second fragmnet,but when i set replace and commit.It's fail.
I tried this function success brfore,but it's not working now.
Is anyone can tell me the problem ? It will be grateful.

The first fragment code:

```
public class StartPage extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    }
    public static StartPage newInstance() {
        return new StartPage();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.start_page_fragment, container, false);

        //findViews();
        imageRegistered = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageRegistered);
        imageRegistered.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FragmentManager fragment=getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction transaction=fragment.beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.frameStartPage,Register.newInstance(),null);
                transaction.commit();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Test",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
        return view;
    }
```

and it's my frameLayout on the Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frameStartPage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.huaweb_system.taiwanuniversityhome.MainActivity">

</FrameLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.hide();

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.frameStartPage, StartPage.newInstance());
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

second fragment:

```
public class Register extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    public static StartPage newInstance() {
        return new StartPage();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.register_activity, container, false);

        findViews();
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`

Comment: My FrameLayout is on the Activity,it's not nest fragment , so i don't think getChildFragmentManager() is correct , even though i try it, the result is crash, error message is E/FragmentManager: No view found for id 0x7f0d0073
thanks for advice,K.

Comment: Show your fragment layout ? Have you added id for fragment?

Comment: sure @Vino , i posted it. You mean android:id="@+id/frameStartPage" right ?

Comment: Yup!! Can you please post your stacktrace too ?

Comment: I'm not sure my stacktrace,but i try to post the other code :MainActivity、second fragment

Comment: transaction.replace(R.id.frameStartPage, StartPage.newInstance()); change this line to  transaction.replace(R.id.frameStartPage, new StartPage());

Comment: thanks @Awadesh , i can change the fragment now. I also change the line transaction.replace(R.id.frameStartPage,new Register(),null);

but why? i though public static StartPage newInstance() {
        return new StartPage();
    }

Comment: and new StartPage() is the same.

Comment: you are welcome :) please have a look at my answer. and accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually getting instance using new operator and using newInstance() static method is same.

Problem is in your code :

```
public static StartPage newInstance() {
    return new StartPage();
}
```

you are using the same method in both the fragments StartPage and Register.

Therefore You should change newInstance method of your Register fragment like this

```
public static Register newInstance() {
    return new Register();
}
```